# Angularjs multiple validations on same textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing angularjs application. I have textbox and i have custom directive attached to it. It should accept certain range of numbers for example between 100 to 200. It is working fine. Along with these validation i want required field validator on submitting form. At a time only one validation should be displayed. Below is my textbox.

```
<div class="inputblock" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : ((form5.$submitted && form5.rangeNumber.$invalid )|| (form5.rangeNumber.$invalid && form5.rangeNumber.$dirty))}">
    <label class="inputblock-label">{{'Down Payment' | translate}}</label>
    <div>
        <span class="ang-error" style="color:#fff" ng-show="form5.rangeNumber.$dirty && form5.rangeNumber.$invalid">
                                     <span ng-show="!(form5.$submitted && form5.rangeNumber.$error.required)&&form5.rangeNumber.$invalid && form5.rangeNumber.$dirty">
                                         {{ 'Value should be between' | translate }} {{min}} {{'and' | translate}} {{max}}
                                     </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <input class="" type="text" name="rangeNumber" ng-attr-placeholder="{{ 'DownPayment' }}" ng-model="DownPayment" range-number="range" required>
</div>
```

[image: validation error]
May i know if this can be done?

Comment: You can use ng-minlength and ng-maxlength to validate range instead of custom directive

Comment: Thank you. I already have directive and it is working as expected.

Comment: What errors are showing together?

Comment: i am able to display only directive error. I have attached error. whenever i select on submit form i want to display required and when the user clicks on textbox then the range message should be displayed.

Comment: So you want to display required error if the above field is empty on submitting of form?

Comment: Yes exactly. When the use clicks on textbox I want to display my custom directive's message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is for directives error.

```
   <span ng-show="form5.rangeNumber.$invalid && form5.rangeNumber.$dirty">
        {{ 'Value should be between' | translate }} {{min}} {{'and' | translate}} {{max}}</span>
       </span>
```

The required error on submitting

```
<span ng-show="form5.$submitted && form5.rangeNumber.$error.required">
          Required*
</span>
```

Combination to avoid both coming together

```
   <span ng-show="!(form5.$submitted && form5.rangeNumber.$error.required)&&form5.rangeNumber.$invalid && form5.rangeNumber.$dirty">
        {{ 'Value should be between' | translate }} {{min}} {{'and' | translate}} {{max}}</span>
       </span>
```

Comment: Thank you.I left office now. Tom I will test

Comment: Okay. let me know if there is any problem

Comment: Hi Vivz. Hope you are doing good. I applied validation but it is overlapping. I have attached screen shot.

Comment: Its working but whenever i enter some invalid number then if i click on submit and come back to textbox and if i clear i get red colour without any text. i have updated my code and picture.

Comment: It is because your ng-class is evaluating to true

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way i can avoid that?

Comment: Try changing your ng-class as f(orm5.$submitted && form5.rangeNumber.$error.required) || (!(form5.$submitted && form5.rangeNumber.$error.required)&&form5.rangeNumber.$invalid && form5.rangeNumber.$dirty)

Comment: But I will strongly suggest you to use ng-minlength and ng-maxlength for your validations because it will be part of form instance and will help you trigger the validations easily. The directive you are using is in no way related to the form instance or the ngModelController instance. So it won't be able to trigger any error by itself. You are using the $invalid and $dirty properties of the form to show the directives error instead of making a directive that will trigger the error irrespective of the form. So basically even if your validations are working, it is not the proper way. :)

Comment: Thank you. I will try to implement standard approaches.